# Ramda applySpec - keep unmodified props

Tags: functional-programming, ramda.js

Let's say I have an object `const foo = { a: 1, b: 2 }` and I want to add a prop c which is based on b.

I could do:

```
applySpec({
    a: prop('a'),
    b: prop('b'),
    c: ({ b }) => b + 1
}, foo)
```

and get an object like: `{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }`

Is there a nicer way to do this?

I've looked at evolve, assoc and applySpec but none of them seems to be fit for purpose.

Comment: @OriDrori answer is excellent. Have you considered `o => ({...o, c: o.b + 1})` though?

Comment: Yes I could do it 'manually' but i was thinking of a more general way of doing this with a bit more complex objects and functions. And OriDroris suggestion was just that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use R.chain to create a function that apply the spec, and then merges the new object with the original one.

If R.chain is used with function (`f` & `g`):
`chain(f, g)(x)` is equivalent to `f(g(x), x)`

In this case `chain(mergeLeft, applySpec({}))` is equal to `mergeLeft(applySpec({}), originalObject)`.

```js
const { chain, mergeLeft, applySpec } = R

const fn = chain(mergeLeft, applySpec({
  c: ({ b }) => b + 1
}))


const foo = { a: 1, b: 2 }

const result = fn(foo)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-rZHvUXcc1zWKsxm7rJ8lVQuIr1oOmm7cShlvpV0gWf0RvbcJN6x96al/Rp2L2BI4a4ZkT2/YfVe/8YvB2UHzQw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

You can make this a generic function that allows adding to existing object, by using R.pipe to pass a curried R.applySpec to the chain:

```js
const { pipe, chain, mergeLeft, applySpec } = R

const fn = pipe(applySpec, chain(mergeLeft))

const addCProp = fn({
  c: ({ b }) => b + 1
})

const foo = { a: 1, b: 2 }

const result = addCProp(foo)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-rZHvUXcc1zWKsxm7rJ8lVQuIr1oOmm7cShlvpV0gWf0RvbcJN6x96al/Rp2L2BI4a4ZkT2/YfVe/8YvB2UHzQw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: This is brilliant! Any idea on what to name this beautiful function 'fn'? :)

Comment: I had an idea of converging with applySpec and identity but this is much cleaner (Y)

Comment: I'm lousy namer. Something like `enhanceSpec` maybe.

Comment: This is great!  We might steal this idea to put into Ramda!

Comment: That's very nice indeed!

Comment: Naming suggestion: withSpec, mergeSpec, applySpec

Comment: Well obviously not applySpec ;)

Comment: @ScottSauyet That would be great :) All my team members had been looking for something similar!