# Pick fields from an object and return one field as an array

Tags: ramda.js

Using Ramda, I am trying to achieve something like this:

```
let data  = {
  'accountNumber' : '12345',
  'holderName' : 'XYZ',
  'id' : '12XX',
  'type' : 'savings',
  ...rest
}

let newObj = R.pick(['accountNumber', 'id', 'type']) (data);

output -> newObj = {
  'accountNumber' : '12345',
  'id' : '12XX',
  'type' : 'savings'
}

I want result like this: 
newObj = {
  'accountNumbers' : ['12345'],
  'id' : '12XX',
  'type' : 'savings'
}
```

I want accountNumber field to be put inside an array of accountNumbers.

I understand pick won't work in this case but I am not able to achieve it through Ramda. It can be done easily using JavaScript but is it possible to achieve via Ramda?

Answer (score 2):

You can pick the properties, and create a new object with changed keys using `R.applySpec()`:

```js
const { applySpec, pipe, of, prop } = R

const fn = applySpec({
  accountNumbers: pipe(prop('accountNumber'), of),
  holderName: prop('holderName'),
  id: prop('id')
})

const data = {
  'accountNumber': '12345',
  'holderName': 'XYZ',
  'id': '12XX',
  'type': 'savings',
}

const result = fn(data)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.28.0/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-t0vPcE8ynwIFovsylwUuLPIbdhDj6fav2prN9fEu/VYBupsmrmk9x43Hvnt+Mgn2h5YPSJOk7PMo9zIeGedD1A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Another option is to add `accountNumbers` using `R.applySpec` (based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65007278/ramda-applyspec-keep-unmodified-props/65007583#65007583)), and then pick the properties, including the updated one from the object:

```js
const { pipe, applySpec, chain, mergeLeft, prop, of, pick } = R

const updateObject = pipe(applySpec, chain(mergeLeft))

const addAccountNumbers = updateObject({
  accountNumbers: pipe(prop('accountNumber'), of)
})

const fn = pipe(addAccountNumbers, pick(['accountNumbers', 'holderName', 'id']))

const data = {
  'accountNumber': '12345',
  'holderName': 'XYZ',
  'id': '12XX',
  'type': 'savings',
}

const result = fn(data)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.28.0/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-t0vPcE8ynwIFovsylwUuLPIbdhDj6fav2prN9fEu/VYBupsmrmk9x43Hvnt+Mgn2h5YPSJOk7PMo9zIeGedD1A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. This solves my 90% problem. Is there any way to change the field name inside returning object from accountNumber to 'accountNumbers' ?

Comment: Missed the `s` there. See updated answer.