# how to update a property in nested json array using ramdajs

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ramda.js

I have an array

```
[
  {
    "offerId": "123",
    "offerStatus": "ACTIVATED",
    "products": [
      {
        "productId": "1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "offerId": "456",
    "offerStatus": "NOT_ACTIVATED",
    "products": [
      {
        "productId": "2"
      },
      {
        "productId": "3"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Want to push(copy) offerStatus into product object, so the
expected output is

```
[
  {
    "offerId": "123",
    "offerStatus": "ACTIVATED",
    "products": [
      {
        "productId": "1",
        "offerStatus": "ACTIVATED"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "offerId": "456",
    "offerStatus": "NOT_ACTIVATED",
    "products": [
      {
        "productId": "2",
        "offerStatus": "NOT_ACTIVATED"
      },
      {
        "productId": "3",
        "offerStatus": "NOT_ACTIVATED"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: can do with 2 nested maps. not familiar with ramda

Comment: `R.map(
  R.evolve({
    products: R.map(R.mergeRight({ offerStatus: 'NOT_ACTIVATED' }))
  }),
  input
)` ?

Answer (score 1):

Map the array, use the `withSpec` utility function (based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65007583/5157454)) to update the `products` using the `offerStatus` of the parent. Then map products, and merge the current `offerStatus`:

```js
const { pipe, applySpec, chain, mergeLeft, map, mergeRight } = R

const withSpec = pipe(applySpec, chain(mergeLeft)) // create new properties using a spec, and add to object

const fn = map(withSpec({
  products: ({ offerStatus, products }) => 
    map(mergeRight({ offerStatus }), products)
}))

const items = [{"offerId":"123","offerStatus":"ACTIVATED","products":[{"productId":"1"}]},{"offerId":"456","offerStatus":"NOT_ACTIVATED","products":[{"productId":"2"},{"productId":"3"}]}]

const result = fn(items)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.29.0/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-5x/n+aOg68Z+O/mq3LW2pC2CvEBSgLl5aLlOJa87AlYM1K8b8qsZ7NTHLe3Hu56aS2W0rgEgVCFA3RM12IXAGw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```